# `# probe: true` in /etc/rc.d/init.d/* files on a RedHat system

Tags: linux, redhat, scripting, chkconfig, init.d

Some files (e.g. `nfs`, `nfslock`, `bind`) in my `/etc/rc.d/init.d/` directory have in their comment header a line such as:

```
# probe: true
```

I found that those particular scripts has the `probe` verb i.e.:

```
service nfs probe
```

But this is due to the fact that the mentioned scripts has code that deals with the `probe` verb.

I find no mention of the `# probe: true` notation in `chkconfig` man page, nor in any related man pages. Googleing for it also didn't help.

Is there a real significance for that line, or is it pure documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "probe" tag is described [here](https://fedorahosted.org/initscripts/browser/sysvinitfiles#L192). Judging from the comments in /etc/init.d/named (from CentOS 5.3), it is used by linuxconf:

```
probe() {
        # named knows how to reload intelligently; we don't want linuxconf
        # to offer to restart every time
        /usr/sbin/rndc reload >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo start
        return $?
}
```

According to the [linuxconf FAQ](http://www.solucorp.qc.ca/howto.hc?projet=linuxconf&id=81), Red Hat stopping using linuxconf after version 7.3, but they apparently haven't removed the probe configuration from some init scripts.

In short, unless you use linuxconf, the probe tag isn't used for anything important.